# Howto achieve animation like store house in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

Hi all i have got to implement storehouse like animation in my project. I found a third party library but sorry it is in swift. Please help me with objective c code

Refference link for animation is

[Animation Store house](https://github.com/SatanWoo/WZStoreHouseTableView)

Comment: you can use swift library in objective-c project and vice-versa

Comment: no i just want that animation idea in objective c code

Comment: I can't see any animation in the link provided

Comment: @VarunNaharia Animation is very minimal. If you observe closely you can see the cell scaling up when it enters mid section and scales down when it moves away from mid section.

Comment: @GoodSp33d  Yeaah corect how to achieve that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StoreTableView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol StoreHouseTableViewTransform


@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scaleValue;
-(void)transFormForCell:(CGFloat)scaleFactor;

@end

@interface StoreTableView : UITableView

@end
```

**StoreTableView.m**

```
#import "StoreTableView.h"

@implementation StoreTableView


-(void)layoutSubviews{
[super layoutSubviews];
[self transformTable];
}

- (void )transformTable{

for (NSIndexPath *indexpath in self.indexPathsForVisibleRows) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];

    if ([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(StoreHouseTableViewTransform)]) {

        UITableViewCell <StoreHouseTableViewTransform> *vc = (UITableViewCell<StoreHouseTableViewTransform> *)cell;
        CGFloat distCenter=[self computeDistance:indexpath];
        [vc transFormForCell:[self computeScale:distCenter withMinScale:vc.scaleValue]];
    }
}

}


-(CGFloat )computeDistance:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{
CGRect rect=[self rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
CGFloat cellCenter=rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2;
CGFloat cellContentCenter=self.contentOffset.y + self.bounds.size.height/2;

return fabs(cellCenter - cellContentCenter);
}

-(CGFloat )computeScale:(CGFloat)distanceOfCenter withMinScale:(CGFloat)scaleFactor{

return (1.0-scaleFactor) * distanceOfCenter / self.bounds.size.height;
}
@end
```

**StoreTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "StoreTableView.h"

@interface StoreTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<StoreHouseTableViewTransform>{
CGFloat minimumScale;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *backView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *scaleImage;

@end
```

**StoreTableViewCell.m**

```
#import "StoreTableViewCell.h"

@implementation StoreTableViewCell
@synthesize scaleValue;

-(void )prepareForReuse{
[super prepareForReuse ];
minimumScale = 0.85;
self.backView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(minimumScale, minimumScale);

}

#pragma mark delegate

-(void)transFormForCell:(CGFloat)scaleFactor{
self.backView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0 - scaleFactor, 1.0 - scaleFactor);
} 
@end
```

This is objective-C implementation of StoreHouse Animation
Subclass your TableView with `StoreTableView` and Cell with `StoreTableViewCell`.
I think so this will help you 
play with scaleFactor

Comment: How to Subclass your TableView with StoreTableView?? If possible please upload a sample project in github and post link or else kindly help me with solution

Comment: this dropbox link of project https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7jgneue4xayxcy/StoreHouseApp.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 4 hours trying to enable Swift in my Xcode Objc-based project. My "myproject-Swift.h" file was created successfully, but my Xcode didn't see my Swift-classes. So I decided to create a new Xcode Objc-based project and finally I found the right answer! Hope this post will help someone :-)
Step by step swift integration for Xcode Objc-based project:

1.Create new *.swift file (in Xcode) or add it by using Finder
2.Add swift bridging empty header if Xcode have not done this before (see 4 below)
3.Implement your Swift class by using @objc attribute:

```
import UIKit

@objc class Hello : NSObject {
    func sayHello () {
        println("Hi there!")
    }
}
```

4.Open Build Settings and check this parameters:
Product Module Name : myproject
Defines Module : YES
Embedded Content Contains Swift : YES
Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
Objective-C Bridging Header : $(SRCROOT)/Sources/SwiftBridging.h
5. Import header (which is auto generated by Xcode) in your *.m file

```
#import "myproject-Swift.h"
```

6. Clean and rebuild your Xcode project

7. Profit

Answer (score 0):

They have open sourced their animation engine. Built on top of CADisplayLink, they recommend this mainly if you're looking to do physics based animations that interact with gestures.
https://github.com/storehouse/Advance